# connect to 3 external display without an external gpu

Tags: motherboard, hdmi, external-display, displayport, asus

I have an ASUS e gaming Z370.  https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z370-e-gaming-model/

There is only 1 dp and 1 hdmi port.

I don't want to buy a graphic card.

I want to connect to 3 displays.

What should I do?

Is it possible that 1 dp could extend to two display?
Is it possible that 1 hdmi could extend to two display?

Comment: There's also a DVI port (which can be passively converted to HDMI or actively to DP). The resolution is capped at 1920*1200 though.

Comment: wow you should put that in answer, thanks bro!